# PostgreSQL - How to convert current timestamp into bytea

Tags: postgresql, data-conversion, bytea

I have migrated a database from SQL Server into PostgreSQL. 
A number of tables contain a `ts` column(`timestamp`) which stores the rowversion and is autogenerated in SQL server.

When I converted the stored procedures into PostgreSQL, I found that insert procedures are failing because the `ts` column (converted to `bytea` in PostgreSQL) is `NOT NULL` and no explicit value is being inserted in this column.

Now, I need to implement the same in PostgreSQL as well. I am assuming encoding the current datetime into `bytea` somehow will work correctly. 
Let me know if there is a way to implement this.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to convert SQL Servers really, really strange "timestamp" data type to anything in Postgres. Just use a real `timestamp` column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was able to convert bytea into integer successfully by using : 
('x'||lpad(encode(ts::bytea, 'hex'), 16, '0'))::bit(64)::bigint

Can't it be reversed?

Comment: I was thinking of encoding current epoch time (bigint) into bytea if above operation could be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

For a timestamp, `timestamp with time zone` is the best data type.

If you want it filled automatically, set the `DEFAULT` value of the column to `current_timestamp`.

There is nothing that keeps you from casting a timestamp first to `text` and then to `bytea`, but what would be gained that way?

Reading up about Microsoft SQL Server's `timestamp` data type, it seems like all you want is a unique identifier for a row version that changes whenever the row is modified.

In PostgreSQL this happens automatically anyway. So you don't need a special column, just use the combination of `xmin` and `ctid`. Both are system columns. If either of these numbers change, the row has been modified.

Comment: SQL Server's `timestamp` is everything but a timestamp. The name is complete bollocks. It's some kind of internal "row version" that is encoded in binary. Maybe it is seeded with a timestamp as the input, but despite the completely confusing name is has nothing to do with a real "timestamp".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it enabled me to make the answer more useful.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, using the system column for this makes sense. However, can you please explain the reason of using combination of `xmin` and `ctid`? 
Will there be any issue if I just use `xmin`?